# FTP connection closes after few hours (2:10) C#, MySQL or Proftpd?

Tags: c#, mysql, ftp, proftpd

My ftp upload takes a few hours, for example 10 hours.

After 1 hour, 48 minutes and 25 seconds (circa!) (= ~ 108 Minutes) the mysql server, the proftpd server or the c# disconnects the connection to the client... (I tried that 5 times)

Or which software is responsible?

**C# Code:**

```
FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.1.3/test-file.zip");
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
req.UsePassive = true;
req.EnableSsl = true;
req.UseBinary = true;
// Upload per req.GetRequestStream .Write
```

**Proftpd-Configuration "timeouts":**

```
TimeoutIdle             1200
TimeoutNoTransfer       600
TimeoutStalled          600
```

**Proftpd-Log:**

```
Oct 20 09:15:43 WD-NAS proftpd[2700] WD-NAS.fritz.box (patrick.fritz.box[192.168.1.2]): FTP session opened.
Oct 20 09:15:51 WD-NAS proftpd[2700] WD-NAS.fritz.box (patrick.fritz.box[192.168.1.2]): Preparing to chroot to directory '/var/www/files'
Oct 20 09:15:51 WD-NAS proftpd[2700] WD-NAS.fritz.box (patrick.fritz.box[192.168.1.2]): USER username: Login successful.
Oct 20 11:04:16 WD-NAS proftpd[2700] WD-NAS.fritz.box (patrick.fritz.box[192.168.1.2]): FTP session closed.
```

**MySQL-Log:**

```
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: defaulting to 'mysql' backend
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: backend module 'mod_sql_mysql/4.0.8'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: backend api    'mod_sql_api_v1'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> sql_sess_init
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_defineconnection
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:   name: 'default'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:   user: 'ftpd'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:   host: 'localhost'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:     db: 'ftpd'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:   port: '3306'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]:    ttl: '0'
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_defineconnection
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' successfully established
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: mod_sql engine     : on
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: negative_cache     : off
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: authenticate       : users groups 
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: usertable          : ftpuser
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: userid field       : userid
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: password field     : passwd
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: UID field          : uid
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: GID field          : gid
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: homedir field      : homedir
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: shell field        : shell
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: group table        : ftpgroup
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: groupname field    : groupname
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: grp GID field      : gid
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: grp members field  : members
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: SQLMinUserUID      : 500
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: SQLMinUserGID      : 500
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: SQLDefaultUID      : 65533
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: SQLDefaultGID      : 65533
Oct 20 09:15:43 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< sql_sess_init
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> sql_pre_pass
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< sql_pre_pass
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_getpwnam
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: MySQL client version: 5.5.35
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: MySQL server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: MySQL connection character set now 'utf8' (from 'UTF-8')
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' opened
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache miss for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: query "SELECT userid, passwd, uid, gid, homedir, shell FROM ftpuser WHERE (userid='username') LIMIT 1"
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache miss for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: user 'username' cached
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: + pwd.pw_name  : username
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: + pwd.pw_uid   : 5500
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: + pwd.pw_gid   : 5500
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: + pwd.pw_dir   : /srv/backups/files
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: + pwd.pw_shell : /sbin/nologin
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_getpwnam
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_gid2name
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache miss for GID '5500'
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: query "SELECT groupname FROM ftpgroup WHERE (gid = 5500) LIMIT 1"
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_gid2name
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_getgroups
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache hit for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache miss for GID '5500'
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: query "SELECT groupname FROM ftpgroup WHERE (gid = 5500) LIMIT 1"
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: query "SELECT groupname, gid, members FROM ftpgroup WHERE (members = 'username' OR members LIKE 'username,%' OR members LIKE '%,username' OR members LIKE '%,username,%')"
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_select
Oct 20 09:15:49 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_getgroups
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_auth
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache hit for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_check
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: checking password using SQLAuthType 'Crypt'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: 'Crypt' SQLAuthType handler reports success
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache hit for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_check
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_auth
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> cmd_getpwnam
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: cache hit for user 'username'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< cmd_getpwnam
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> log_master (SQLLog_PASS)
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: >>> process_named_query 'updatecount'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_escapestring
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_update
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 2
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: query "UPDATE ftpuser SET count=count+1, accessed=now() WHERE userid='username'"
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 1
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_update
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< process_named_query 'updatecount'
Oct 20 09:15:51 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: <<< log_master (SQLLog_PASS)
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_exit
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: entering     mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' closed
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: connection 'default' count is now 0
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_close
Oct 20 11:04:16 mod_sql/4.3[2700]: exiting  mysql cmd_exit
```

**C# Error:**

```
2014-10-20 11:04:15 System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..
```

I searched on stack**overflow** and found something about the C# timeout and some bugs with that.

But is it true that Microsoft cant fix that problem? Is it too difficult to fix the problem?

Comment: `is it true that Microsoft cant fix that problem` I guess they have more important things to fix than some kind of **10 hours upload** bug(if that exists at all)

Answer (score 0):

Thіs sounds like a TCP timeout on the command channel. Disconnection is initiated by the TCP stack due to inactivity. To prevent this the client needs to send so-called keep-alive signals. For FTP the NOOP command is used. I am not sure that you can do this with built-in FTPclient of .NET framework, though.

Comment: There is an upload... I think that should be "activity" ^^

Comment: @PatrickB Data transfer is done over data channel and it's a command channel which is closed due to inactivity.

Comment: A bit late, but for keepalives on the FTP _control_  connection (which as @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp mentioned is *idle* while the _data_ connection, a *separate* TCP connection, is busy with the upload), you can use TCP-level keepalive (`req.KeepAlive = true`), and [FTP-level keepalives](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/KeepAlives.html).  You would send this "noop" in the middle of your upload/write() loop.  Given that C# doesn't appear to support the actual `NOOP` FTP command, I'd suggest `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory`.